# Data not displayed correctly when using addSnapshotListener in Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am using `addSnapshotListener` to get the data in real time.

When data is added to my Firestore database, I get an unexpected result:

```
func addItem(title: String) {
    self.db.collection("items").document(stage.stageId).setData([
        "title": title,
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

For example, if items are empty and you execute `addItem (title:" Test ")` once, three data items with the title "Test" are displayed in the `ListView`.

```
struct ListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetcher = Fetcher()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.fetcher.data.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                Text(self.fetcher.data[idx].title)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Fetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [ItemModel] = []
    private var db: Firestore!

    init() {
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        fetchData()
    }

    private func fetchData() {
        self.db.collection("items").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            }

            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            for document in documents {
                self.data.append(ItemModel(
                    title: document.data()["title"]as! String,
                ))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ItemModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code above?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `ItemModel` implement `Identifiable`? That's required so the `ListView` can tell the elements apart. Also, I was wondering if you use Firestore via Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem the other day. commentElements is my class and comments is my published variable. I think the id: .self was the problem but I don't remember exactly. (I had 3 comment documents stored on Firebase, but it was only returning the first comment 3 times.

```
List {
            ForEach(commentElements.comments, id: \.comment) { item in
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                HStack {
                    Text("")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.regular)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    Text("said on \(self.newComment.date.dateValue())")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.thin)
                }
                Text(item.comment).font(.footnote).bold()
```